# Laravel unique validation Ignore Rule for update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have a `name` field on my `Client` model which must be unique. For the `store` method I have the following rules:

```
array (
  'token' => 'string|max:250',
  'directory' => 'max:250',
  'name' => 'required|string|max:250|unique:clients',
)
```

For the `update` method, I have amended this ruleset to ignore the current ID to avoid a duplicate being identified:
`$rules['name'] = $rules['name'] . ',id,' . $id;`

This produces the following ruleset (for record ID 105):

```
array (
  'token' => 'string|max:250',
  'directory' => 'max:250',
  'name' => 'required|string|max:250|unique:clients,id,105',
)
```

When the `update` method is executed, the `The name has already been taken.` response is returned during the validation.

I realise this is a well-discussed topic, but believe I am conforming to the correct approach. Can someone point out the error in my logic, please?

*Note: This is running on Laravel 5.8.*

Comment: I would recommend you to use clockwork to see what query is executed behind the scenes, it will be helpful to debug  about the rule details. https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork

Comment: @Ersoy thanks for the suggestion... the above script is being used on a RESTful API, does Clockwork offer feedback for that approach?

Comment: yes if you capture request then replay (xhr) and see the queries too.

Comment: if it is hard to do(capture) it  - you may open a TestController/index method and inject your Request class into the index method, a dummy route - and make a request from chrome console to that dummy route bind to test controller/index.

Comment: Thanks @Ersoy, I didn't end up using it, but I'll keep it in mind for the future. Appreciate the information!

Answer (score 0):

```
array(
    'token' => 'string|max:250',
    'directory' => 'max:250',
    'name' => [
        'required', 'string', 'max:250',
        \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique(Client::class, 'email')->ignore($this->id)
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close. I've submitted an edit with the functional code revisions. I shall accept the answer once the edit has been approved.

Comment: I'm keen to understand why the pipe delimited approach doesn't work though... has support for this approach been dropped, or was I approaching it the right way.